# Android animation ends quickly

Tags: android

I am having the following problem: I have an animation in my android app that moves a UI elements at the screen, i.e. it is a translate animation, it generally works fine. Let us say that it is moving from position (0,0) to (0, 200) in the screen. The problem is, sometimes this happens very quickly (like 0.001 seconds) and as soon as the program is loaded, i do not see the movement of the object but i see that it is at the final position(0,200). Here is my code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

float height;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutDoughnutAndLogoTogether;
private RelativeLayout logo_donut_together2;
private ImageView imgSplash, image2;
private DoughnutView doughnutView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    relativeLayoutDoughnutAndLogoTogether = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.logo_donut_together);
    logo_donut_together2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.logo_donut_together2);
    imgSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.turkcell_logo);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);

    int logoHeight = imgSplash.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    final int centerScreen = (screenHeight-logoHeight)/2;

    doughnutView = new DoughnutView(this) {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationComplete() {
                float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                Animation moveToTop = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, centerScreen-50*density, 0);
                moveToTop.setDuration(1000);                        
                relativeLayoutDoughnutAndLogoTogether.startAnimation(moveToTop);                    

                logo_donut_together2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                logo_donut_together2.removeView(doughnutView);
                relativeLayoutDoughnutAndLogoTogether.addView(doughnutView);                            
                relativeLayoutDoughnutAndLogoTogether.setVisibility(0);
        }
    };


    doughnutView.setStartAngle(0);
    doughnutView.setColorFront(Color.rgb(232, 232, 232));
    doughnutView.setSweepAngle(360);
    doughnutView.setStrokeWidth(4);
    doughnutView.setMarginAll(10);
    doughnutView.setColorBack(Color.rgb(63, 176, 232));
    doughnutView.startAnimation(0);
    logo_donut_together2.addView(doughnutView);

}
```

I am actually talking about the onAnimationComplete part of the code. I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write the logic on onAnimatinEnd(Animation animation){...}
    this may helps you...

```
relativeLayoutDoughnutAndLogoTogether.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            logo_donut_together2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            logo_donut_together2.removeView(doughnutView);
            relativeLayoutDoughnutAndLogoTogether.addView(doughnutView);                            
            relativeLayoutDoughnutAndLogoTogether.setVisibility(0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```